# Android support Toolbar + ActionBarDrawerToggle not changing to arrow

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar, drawertoggle

I'm struggling with the toolbar and drawer. I'm trying to make the burger switch to arrow when I'm adding a new fragment to the backstack but there is no way to do it.

Maybe I'm missing something but I could not find a way. Anyone had the same problem?

This is the declaration:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivityCompat(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            ((BaseActivity) getActivityCompat()).getToolbar(),
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    )
```

This is the function I call when a fragment is added to the back stack

```
public void setToggleState(boolean isEnabled) {
    if (mDrawerLayout == null)
        return;

    if (isEnabled) {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        mDrawerToggle.onDrawerStateChanged(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        mDrawerToggle.onDrawerStateChanged(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    }
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. In my current workaround, i just popup a new Activity with the Fragment and up enabled, where in reality I want to add the Fragment to the backstack and animate the drawer toggle to an up arrow.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think all you have to do is to delete the third argument. Thus:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
     getActivityCompat(),              /* host Activity */
     mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
     // ((BaseActivity) getActivityCompat()).getToolbar(), <== delete this argument
     R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
     R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    );
```

May it helps.

Comment: doesn't work. there is no longer the toogle icon in my toolbar. :(

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem. My solution was this:

Make sure your activity implements onBackStackChangedListener. In your activities' onCreate I set the backstack listener and I set up the toolbar

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFm = getFragmentManager();
    mFm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);

    // Setup toolbar
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    // Setup drawer toggle
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.menu_open, R.string.menu_close);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    // Setup initial fragment
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mCurrentFragment = DashboardFragment.newInstance();
        mFm.beginTransaction().add(CONTAINER_ID, mCurrentFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Also remember to set:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Now the magic happens in onBackStackChanged(). Setting the setDrawerIndicatorEnabled to true for the top-most fragment and setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled as false for that fragment. Inverse for the other ones. I also had to call syncState or else the hamburger wouldn't reappear:

```
@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(mFm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(mFm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Comment: Thanks...it worked..Can u tell me how to animate Home Button to Back button...Thanks again

Comment: @ShashankKumar I've been having issues with that myself. You can manually call mDrawerToggle.onDrawerSlide(null, [VALUE]) where value is between 0-1. So to animate you would have to do something like:
        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                mDrawerToggle.onDrawerSlide(null, (float)animation.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });
        anim.setDuration(300);
        anim.start();

Comment: @ShashankKumar the issue with this though is that the syncState function resets the hamburger state so you need to find a solution to that :).

Comment: hi hordurh ,
try this after your code
anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
                }
            });
anim.setDuration(300); anim.start();

Comment: above comment did solve the animation problem ...but ican't to the reverse animation i.e. Back>Home...i tried changing ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1, 0);  but that didn't work

Comment: This works brilliantly, except that the back button doesn't actually go back. I presume I need to wire that up to pop the fragment.

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved it using following layout:
i have used ActionBarDrawerToggle v7
Drawer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.toolbar.Drawer" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool1"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />



    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tool1" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- Nav drawer -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawerList"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:divider="@android:color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="8dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app1:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app1:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Drawer.java

package com.example.toolbar;

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Drawer extends ActionBarActivity {

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] days;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer);

        days = new String[] { "sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
                "thursday", "friday", "saturday" };
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, days);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString(MyFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, days[position]);
                // args.putInt(MyFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment).commit();

            }

        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool1);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("ToolBar Demo");
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar,
                R.string.open_navigation_drawer,
                R.string.close_navigation_drawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("hello");
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("hi");
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //<---- added
        // getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); //<---- added

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { // <---- added
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // <---- added
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState(); // important statetment for drawer to
                                    // identify
                                    // its state
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) { // <---- added
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START | Gravity.LEFT)) { // <----
                                                                        // added
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: but when you add a new fragment to the backstack does the burger become an arrow?

Comment: i haven't tried it yet with stack of fragments but its working fine(burger become an arrow) when i have multiple activities..I think this will work when you add a new fragment .

Comment: What is the parent theme used in the above example in styles.xml? I tried using <style name="AppTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">, but I am getting error.

Comment: I have not used Actionbar instead i have used toolbar <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item></style>

Answer (score 2):

@hata's answer is spot-on for most cases.

But actually, you were not wrong using toolbar as argument to the `ActionBarDrawerToggle(...)` constructor.

Of course, there's no sense in doing that if you're using the stock `Toolbar` `AppCompatActivity` provides by using, say the stock `Theme.AppCompat.Light` root theme.
Even if you want a custom `Toolbar` in your layout, e.g. if you're implementing the Material Design's over-toolbar-under-statusbar Navigation Drawer pattern, you can still call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` and still not pass the toolbar to `ActionBarDrawerToggle()` letting the activity handle the navigation icon.

But if you really want to bind your `ActionBarDrawerToggle` to a `Toolbar` that's not activity's action bar, and maybe has different styling and a different icon or whatever -- there's still a way to go.

The thing is, when you don't pass the toolbar as the fourth parameter, the activity is supposed to provide the navigation icon (the arrow) -- and `AppCompatActivity` returns the value of `homeAsUpIndicator` attribute -- it's defined in either of the standard AppCompat themes.

However, when you explicitly pass the `Toolbar`, `ActionBarDrawerToggle` expects the toolbar instance to provide the navigation indicator drawable -- and it doesn't, because even if you apply the appropriate style to it like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ...
        app:theme="?actionBarTheme"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
```

for some reason (maybe it's even a bug), the `Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar` style doesn't have `navigationIcon` attribute, so `Toolbar` returns `null` when `ActionBarDrawerToggle` asks it for the nav icon. So, to cope with this, you simply derive from the style and add the attribute:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ...
        app:theme="?actionBarTheme"
        style="@style/MyWidget.Toolbar">
<!-- styles.xml -->
<style name="MyWidget.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="navigationIcon">?homeAsUpIndicator</item>
</style>
```

Now you can use the toolbar-aware constructor `ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, 0, 0)` and still have the navigation icon in place.

Answer (score 1):

this line makes sure hamburger icon is changed to arrow on clicking. Make sure you have this written in your code.

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```